# How to use clean and fclean in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to using Makefile and I'm struggling to make it work correctly.

I want to compile my files to an executable .o file and then remove all the other .o files that were created in the process.

```
SRC = ./main.c \
      ./rush00.c \
      ./ft_putchar.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -Wextra

NAME = rushB

all:$(NAME)

$(NAME):$(OBJ)
    cc -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean $(NAME)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Is there a way to make an executable file without creating main.o, rush00.o and ft_putchar.o?

Comment: To answer: `Is there a way to make an executable file without creating main.o, rush00.o and ft_putchar.o?` Do you really want this? This means that all files would be compiled over and over again? Whereas make is now only compiling the files that are out of date. This speeds up your workflow greatly when your project grows.

Comment: Under `all:` you could add a line like `$(CC) -o $(NAME) $(SRC)` (precided by a tab) I think, but I think most people would like the makefile better as it is.

Comment: Generally speaking, one would *not* routinely remove the `.o` files.  Retaining them permits you to avoid rebuilding them when the corresponding source files are unchanged since the last build.